# Change views to edit mode in View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, edit, uislider

I want to be an user to be able to enter into Edit mode when on a view controller where then they can edit the screen values which has textfields and sliders.

I followed this doc so far:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/EnablingEditModeinaViewController/EnablingEditModeinaViewController.html

and used this part of the code

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)flag animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:flag animated:animated];
    if (flag == YES){
        // Change views to edit mode.
    }
    else {
        // Save the changes if needed and change the views to noneditable.
    }
}
```

how can you change views to be in edit mode? I want my user to be able to edit the input in the textFields and the value of the slider.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `if(flag == YES)` part, you can set the `editable` property of your `UITextField`s to `YES` like so :

```
textField.editable = YES;
```

In the `else` part, you have to set the `UITextField`s back to their non-editable state like so:

```
textField.editable = NO;
```

For `UISlider`s, use the `slider.enabled` property.

I hope this helps you.